# Algebraic equation $(-2x^2y)^3 \div x^5y \div (-2x^2y^2) =$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to answer the following problem: $(-2x^2y)^3 \div  x^5y \div  (-2x^2y^2) =$

I have the key with the answer $4\div x$ and have confirmed this is correct using Wolfram Alpha but which steps do I take to get to that answer?

Comment: This is ambiguous without more parentheses; does $A \div B \div C$ mean $(A \div B) \div C$ or $A \div (B \div C)$?

Comment: @Clive Newstead, the problem has been presented exactly as in the source so in this case it is to be interpreted from the presentation provided here. My interpretation is $(A \div B) \div C$ which to me is the same as $A \div B \div C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the $\div$ notation, you can write your expression as a fraction, namely: $$\cfrac{\dfrac{(-2x^2y)^3}{x^5y}}{-2x^2y^2}.$$
Then use the fact that $\rm\dfrac{\dfrac AB}{C}=\dfrac AB\dfrac1C$.

Comment: Solved using this method, however there is a typo in the first denominator in the fraction you wrote, it should be $x^5y$.

Comment: @user14124 Thanks, fixed! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

To simplify the fractions, you may consider them as follows:

[image]

Indeed, we multiply far items ($A$ and $D$) and put the result ($A\times D$) in numerator and multiply close parts ($B$ and $C$) and then put the result at denominator.